# How do I do an async query without enumerating the data?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to work out how to write a generic async `GetAll<T>` database method in Entity Framework Core without enumerating the data. I want `GetAll<T>` to be async, but don't want it to enumerate the data, so that I can add a `Where` method afterwards, and have that applied to the database query..

```
List<Customer> customers = await _customerRepository.GetAll()
  .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("a"))
  .ToList();
```

[MSDN's article on async queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async) shows the following...

```
public async Task<List<Blog>> GetBlogsAsync()
{
    using (var context = new BloggingContext())
    {
        return await context.Blogs.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

...but (if I understand it correctly) the call to `ToListAsync()` will enumerate the data, meaning it will load the entire `Blogs` data set into memory, and only afterwards apply any filtering that a `Where` method applied to the result would specify.

Can I have an async method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` instead?

I'm quite happy not to use a repository if that's a better way to do it. [This article](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/) suggests that EF Core doesn't benefit from repositories, but I can't see how to do what I want his way either.

**Update**: To clarify (thanks to DavidG), the idea is that my ASP.NET Core controllers can have an injected repository, and can do an async query to get the data. I was thinking of making the repository generic, and doing the filtering in the controller, hence the question. I know I can write a `CustomersRepository` and have a `CustomersThatStartWith` method, but then the repository gets bloated. I was looking for as simple a repository as posisble.

Comment: You would need to return `IQueryable<T>` and not do `ToList`. Also it can't be async as it's not doing any work yet. However, perhaps this is an XY problem. Why do you want to apply `Where` filters later?

Comment: Couldnt you just extend your repository with something like `GetWhereStartsWithLetter(char letter)`?. You could also just return an `IQueryable<T>` from your repository, and call `ToListAsync()` from the caller, but that wouldn't be "cleanest" solution when working with repositories.

Comment: @MarcoSiffert The problem with exposing `IQueryable`s is that you allow callers to do all sort of potentially dangerous things with your database.

Comment: @DavidG Please see the update I just added, maybe that will help. I'm quite prepared to accept I'm asking the wrong question!

Comment: Would you be OK with a `GetAll` method that allows you to supply a filter then?

Comment: @DavidG Absolutely, that's what I was originally intending

Comment: Just my opinion.
Usually we don't use repository with EF at all.
You can have one more layer for BusinessLogic and work there with Context and IQueryable directly - EF it's your repository+UOW :)
Your presentation layer(Controllers) doesn't know about context, you have to work with business layer and return just stupid data to your controller where you can map everything to viewModel.

Comment: And you don't need to create context through (using) block every time when you want to make a request. But be careful to work with huge lists you should add .AsNoTracking() before Execute your query if it just read data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The safest thing to do is allow your caller (in your case the controller, though I would recommend keeping your logic outside of them) to pass in their own filters. Something like this for example:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync<T>(params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] filters)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();    

    if(filters != null)
    {
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
    }

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var allUsers = await repository.GetAsync<User>();

var zombies = await repository.GetAsync<User>(u => u.IsUndead == true);

var zombieDevelopers = await repository.GetAsync<User>(
    u => u.IsUndead = true,
    u => u.JobTitle = "Developer");
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. One quick question before I mark it as the answer, in order to use Linq methods on the List<T> that comes back, I seem to have to wrap the `await repository.GetAsync<User>()` part in brackets, eg `(await repository.GetAsync<User>()).FirstOrDefault()`, which clutters the code. Is there a way to allow me to call Linq methods directly on the result? Thanks again.

Comment: Or just do Linq methods on the returned object. Like `allUsers.First()`

Comment: Yes, but that means splitting the query into two. I like to use expression-bodied methods where possible, and adding the Linq method on the end of the query allows that. Splitting the query doesn't.

Comment: Well you either do that or use brackets.

Comment: OK, just wondered if there was a way to avoid them. Thanks again for the help, I'll mark this as the answer.